# How to rewrite example.com/api/v1 requests to api.example2.com/v1?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a nginx server that accepts requests of "example.com" site:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/site;
  index index.html index.htm;

  /api {
     ??? (need to proxy the requests to api.example2.com)
  }
}
```

When it comes to the api I need to redirect all the requests to subdomain of another server e.g:

```
example.com/api/v1 -> api.example2.com/v1
```

How could I achieve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try: `location /api/ { proxy_pass http://api.example2.com/; }`

Comment: Doesn't work. It produces http://api.example2.com/api/v1 request